# WPF Custom DataColumn Headers with Dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, datagrid

I have a dictionary of strings, and I want to bind it to a DataGrid in WPF.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DictionaryClass}">
        <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding StringDictionary}">
        </DataGrid>
</DataTemplate>
```

This creates two columns as expected, however the two columns have headers "Key" and "Value" respectively. I know I can change the `HeadersVisibility` property, how can I set my own custom column headers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to disable the auto-generation of the column, and define it manually.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Text 1" Binding="{Binding Key}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Text 2" Binding="{Binding Value}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```